# OLE DB: Failed to update database "master" because the database is read-only

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I use PowerBI and when I want to connect read-only database and make only select queries it says

OLE DB: Failed to update database "master" because the database is read-only.

In my queries there is no "update" query.

All queries are "select" queries.

Has anybody ever seen error like that ?

I have searched a lot and couldn't find any real solution.

Comment: Why is your `master` database in a read-only state in the first place? Have you suffered some significant errors on the instance, or something?

Comment: I dont know why Master is read-only. I m not db admin. Should we convert master to read-write ? It's Azure database BTW

Comment: What does "in Azure" mean, is it a Azure SQL Database, or a SQL Server instance hosted in Azure?

Comment: it's Azure SQL Database

Comment: Then why are you referencing the `master` database at all? Azure SQL Databases are isolated databases; you should be connecting directly to the database you are using. You can't use 3 part naming in Azure SQL Database, so there should be no references to `master`.

Comment: well, I dont reference to master, I never do anything with master database.  It's normal select queries for me. When it runs it gives me error like that. I will search "3 part naming" thing . Thanks for your help.

Comment: So what is the query you're actually running here? Are you certain you're connecting to the correct database, and not `master` in error?